# How to generate a sequence of numbers increasing at a fixed percentage?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the predicted value at 2% growth rate over 10 years.

My data looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(fin_year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021
 ), Total = c(136661.9, 142748.25, 146580.77, 155486.07, 171115.58, 
              69265.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I would like to add a new column (two_percent) with the calculated amounts based on the 2016 Total value.

I expect the answers to look like this:

[image]

I've tried this but can't figure out how to code the script properly to do what I want

```
df1 <- df %>% 
      mutate(two_percent = rep(Total[1:1] *1.02))
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The formula is 1.02^n where n is the number of periods.  One may need to subtract 1 from n depending on whether the interest is at the beginning or end of the period.

```
basevalue <- df$Total[1]
df1 <- df %>% 
   mutate(two_percent = basevalue*1.02^(row_number()-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `purrr::accumulate` to calculate the 2% growth forecast. First let's calculate this for the existing `data.frame`. We need to supply a vector of `1.02` in the length of one less than the total row number to  `accumulate`s  `.x` argument. Further, we need the base value of `Total` as `.init` argument (this is the value we want to base the forecast on). The function `.f` that we then use is just `.x * .y`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Calculate the growth rate for the existing data.frame
df %>% 
  mutate(two_percent = accumulate(rep(1.02, nrow(.)-1),
                                  ~ .x * .y,
                                  .init = first(Total)))
#>   fin_year     Total two_percent
#> 1     2016 136661.90    136661.9
#> 2     2017 142748.25    139395.1
#> 3     2018 146580.77    142183.0
#> 4     2019 155486.07    145026.7
#> 5     2020 171115.58    147927.2
#> 6     2021  69265.01    150885.8
```

While this works for the existing `data.frame` we need a new one, if we want to forecast values for years that the current `df` doesn't contain. Basically, we use the same approach as above and combine it with a `right_join`:

```r
# Calculate the growth rate for a 10 year period, and then join
new_df <- tibble(Year = 1:10,
                 two_percent = df$Total[1]) %>% 
  mutate(two_percent = accumulate(rep(1.02, nrow(.)-1),
                                  ~ .x * .y,
                                  .init = first(two_percent)))
df %>% 
  mutate(Year = row_number()) %>% 
  right_join(new_df)
#> Joining, by = "Year"
#>    fin_year     Total Year two_percent
#> 1      2016 136661.90    1    136661.9
#> 2      2017 142748.25    2    139395.1
#> 3      2018 146580.77    3    142183.0
#> 4      2019 155486.07    4    145026.7
#> 5      2020 171115.58    5    147927.2
#> 6      2021  69265.01    6    150885.8
#> 7        NA        NA    7    153903.5
#> 8        NA        NA    8    156981.6
#> 9        NA        NA    9    160121.2
#> 10       NA        NA   10    163323.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple method that anchors the base of the `Two_percent` calculation to the value of `Total` in the first `fin_year` using `which.min(fin_year)`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(fin_year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021
), Total = c(136661.9, 142748.25, 146580.77, 155486.07, 171115.58, 
             69265.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df %>% 
  mutate(two_percent = Total[which.min(fin_year)] * 1.02^(seq_along(fin_year)))
#>   fin_year     Total two_percent
#> 1     2016 136661.90    139395.1
#> 2     2017 142748.25    142183.0
#> 3     2018 146580.77    145026.7
#> 4     2019 155486.07    147927.2
#> 5     2020 171115.58    150885.8
#> 6     2021  69265.01    153903.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>